# Provide a user-request when homeButton in actionbar was pressed

Tags: java, android

i want to provide a appropriate onUp-Navigation. Like shown in following codesnippet for onBackPressed(), i want to do a  request, if the user really want to go back to the parent activity (because data maybe not saved, so i want to warn), when the homebutton in the actionBar was pressed. For onbackPressed it works fine.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Mal ein anderer Weg für einen Bestätigungs
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Really Exit?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            NewAndEditActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }).create().show();

}
```

But when i try to run this:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onNavigateUp() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Mal ein anderer Weg für einen Bestätigungs
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        NewAndEditActivity.super.onNavigateUp();
                    }
                }).create().show();

            return false;
        }
```

The Diaolog is shown shortly, but the process "go back" goes on.

Have one of you any idea? Thanks a lot!

Edit: I found a solution.
Apparently i have to undo teh parent-activity declaration for this activity. after that, no auto-progress occured and i can provide a appropriate user-request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can listen for when the home button is pressed:

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      // Display the dialog
      return true; 
    } 
  return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. but there i have the same problem. the dialog is shown shortly, then the parent activity appears. no cance to cancel the homeup-command.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a proper solution, but instead of calling the super methods you could finish you activity yourself in this case

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Mal ein anderer Weg für einen Bestätigungs
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Really Exit?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            NewAndEditActivity.finish();
        }
    }).create().show();
}
```